# Hide Hamburger Menu on Specific Page in WordPress Site

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress, hamburger-menu

[TheHamburgerCollection.com](http://thehamburgercollection.com/)

My hamburger menu is working correctly on all other pages - I just don't want it to display on the home page, where it's currently visible at 768px and below.

footer.php is where the menu is located:

```
<div class="mobile-nav">
    <div class="menu-btn" id="menu-btn">
        <div></div>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
    </div>

    <div class="responsive-menu">
    <?php
        if ( ! is_front_page() && ! is_home() ) {
        wp_nav_menu();  
        } 
    ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can see that I've told it not to display the nav menu on the front page (which is also the home page), and it's doing this correctly - but how do I do the same thing to the hamburger menu?

I followed the instructions in [this tutorial](http://www.internetkultur.at/hamburger-drop-with-css-javascript-multi-level-menus/) to create my hamburger menu. If I try to copy the PHP if statement that's telling the browser to display the Nav Menu on all other pages except for the Front Page / Home Page and then paste it just before the div with class and id "menu-btn", I get a syntax error:

```
<div class="mobile-nav">
    <?php if ( ! is_front_page() && ! is_home() ) {
        <div class="menu-btn" id="menu-btn">
            <div></div>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </div>
    } 
    ?>

    <div class="responsive-menu">
    <?php
        if ( ! is_front_page() && ! is_home() ) {
        wp_nav_menu();  
    } 
    ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure if there's a way to hide the hamburger menu on a specific page with CSS, or, if I do need to use PHP or JS, where should I place the function / what function should I use?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must close php code section before you print HTML code.

```
<div class="mobile-nav">
    <?php if ( ! is_front_page() && ! is_home() ) : ?>
        <div class="menu-btn" id="menu-btn">
            <div></div>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?> 

    <div class="responsive-menu">
    <?php
        if ( ! is_front_page() && ! is_home() ) {
        wp_nav_menu();  
    } 
    ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing the `HTML` with your `PHP`.

**Try this:**

```
<?php if ( ! is_front_page() && ! is_home() ) { ?>
    <div class="menu-btn" id="menu-btn">
        <div></div>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

**Explanation:**

As you can see you have the `<div>...</div>` inside of your `PHP`. 
You need to close first your `php-section`, then post your `html`, and then you have to end your `if`.

You just need a `?>` after your `if(...) {`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah makes sense - now I know how to correctly close a PHP section / end an If statement!

Answer (score 1):

You can do like that:

```
 <?php if ( ! is_front_page() && ! is_home() ) {
<div class="mobile-nav">
        <div class="menu-btn" id="menu-btn">
            <div></div>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </div>


    <div class="responsive-menu">
    <?php
        wp_nav_menu();  
    ?>
    </div>
</div>
 } 
 ?>
```